# Need to set HTTP Only Flag for cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-cookies, httpcookie

I understand there are countless topics out there for this solution but I already have a code set up and need to modify only on this hence, any help would be very much appreciated. 
setting the web.config does not fix the issue...

```
 <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" lockItem="true" />
```

and setting up ssl is not an option for now so the only way out remaining is modifying the existing code. 
my code on page Load is this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (Session["New"] != null && Session["AuthToken"] != null && Request.Cookies["AuthToken"] != null)
       {
    if (!Session["AuthToken"].ToString().Equals(Request.Cookies["AuthToken"].Value))
       { Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");}
        }
        else
        {Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");}
        }
```

I came across this Sample Code to fix this one which says it should go under the Page_Load event but I am not able to figure out how to go about it.
Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly.aspx

```
HttpCookie myHttpCookie = new HttpCookie("LastVisit", DateTime.Now.ToString());
myHttpCookie.Name = "MyHttpCookie";
Response.AppendCookie(myHttpCookie);
Response.Write(myHttpCookie.Name);
HttpCookie myHttpOnlyCookie = new HttpCookie("LastVisit",DateTime.Now.ToString());
myHttpOnlyCookie.HttpOnly = true;
myHttpOnlyCookie.Name = "MyHttpOnlyCookie";
Response.AppendCookie(myHttpOnlyCookie);
Response.Write(myHttpOnlyCookie.Name);
```

My log out click event code is this

```
 if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = string.Empty;
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(20);
        }
        if (Request.Cookies["AuthToken"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["AuthToken"].Value = string.Empty;
            Response.Cookies["AuthToken"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-20);
        }
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```